# GCC links to library that does not exist

Tags: linux, linker, icu

Will two libraries together produce a third library that does not even exist?

Try it [here](https://github.com/aleck099/strange-cases)

Make sure there are [icu](https://icu.unicode.org/) and g++ on your machine

##### Output

```
ldd out1:
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd5cdaf000)
    liblcf.so.0 => /home/aleck099/.local/lib/liblcf.so.0 (0x00007ff200600000)
    libicuuc.so.72 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.72 (0x00007ff200200000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff1ffe00000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff200518000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff2008a1000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff1ffc19000)
    libicui18n.so.71 => not found
    libicuuc.so.71 => not found
    libicudata.so.71 => not found
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007ff200874000)
    libicudata.so.72 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.72 (0x00007ff1fde00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff2008ea000)
ldd out2:
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdfed78000)
    libicui18n.so.72 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.72 (0x00007fa088000000)
    libicuuc.so.72 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.72 (0x00007fa087c00000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa087800000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa08834d000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa087fe0000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa087619000)
    libicudata.so.72 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.72 (0x00007fa085800000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa08845e000)
```

You can see that three "not found"s in the ldd output of `out1`

They are even duplicates of existing icu libraries

How could this happen?

##### Other information

- both clang and gcc produce the same result
- `liblcf.so` is built from [easyrpg](https://easyrpg.org/downloads/player/0.7.0/liblcf-0.7.0.tar.xz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the link command used to create `out1` picked up symbols from two different versions of the ICU library: `libicuuc.so.71` and `libicuuc.so.72`. The 71 vs 72 is the version number. Those appear to be two different versions of the shared library that were both in the linker's library path. It's "not found" at `ldd` time because one copy is not in the runtime shared library search path, and even if it was mixing both is probably a bad idea.

The solution is likely to inspect your link command and ensure the `-L` options only include one version/copy of the ICU library.

EDIT: Linking with verbosity enabled (`g++ -v` option) will provide additional information about the libraries and paths being used.

Note that it's possible that some of the shared libraries pulled in by `out1` are transitively pulling in the (non-existent) `libicuuc.so.71`. Comparing your two `ldd` executable outputs, I would be suspicious of `/home/aleck099/.local/lib/liblcf.so.0` (and possibly `/usr/lib/libexpat.so.1`) that only appear in `out1`. The following command may help:

```bash
$ ldd /home/aleck099/.local/lib/liblcf.so.0 /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1
```

Comment: Right.  liblcf.so depends on libicuuc.so.72, so a possible solution is to move liblcf.so to a separate directory with no other .so files, and specify that directory instead of `-L.` when building `out1`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck 's solution does not work, the problem is that there is **NO** libicu*.so.71 on my whole file system (I've executed `find / -name '*so.71*'` under root many times), how does gcc come up with that version of 71?

Comment: @aleck099 see my EDIT above

Comment: @user28731 Thank you! I created another brand new user and rebuilt everything, they workd well